# How to Mass-Replace Incorrect "wp-admin" Internal Links with Public URLs in WordPress Posts?

Tags: wordpress

Hi WordPress Community,

I've encountered a challenging issue on our company's WordPress blog and I'm hoping for some expert insights or solutions.

**The Problem:**
We recently noticed that many internal links within our blog posts are incorrectly using "wp-admin" URLs. These links, understandably, lead to access errors for our readers since they point to the administrative side of WordPress rather than the intended public content.

For example, a typical incorrect link looks like this:
https://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=123&action=edit

But it should simply be:
https://example.com/correct-post-slug/

There are a few hundred posts with this issue, and manually updating each link isn't feasible.

**What I'm Looking For:**
I'm seeking a way to bulk-update these incorrect "wp-admin" URLs to their correct public counterparts throughout all posts.

**What I've Tried:**

I considered using a plugin like "Better Search Replace," but I'm unsure how to target these specific "wp-admin" URLs accurately without impacting other necessary elements.

Are there any other methods or tools that could solve this issue more efficiently?

I'm looking for the most efficient and safe way to correct this on a large scale with minimal risks of breaking other functionalities.

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance you can provide!